# How can I use Part Assignment to change sublists into other sublists (without changing levels)?

Tags: color, assignment, partitions, list-manipulation

Here's a 5x5 grid. Using predefined starting points, I'd like to change some sublists into something else (e.g., the values for a color, "drawing an opaque box").

```
list = 
{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}};
```

This seems simple enough, use the Part command to change all of the elements via:

*Part[{list}, startingrow;;endingrow, startingelement;;endingelement] = assignment;*

(Now use the new list for whatever you like)

This works totally as expected if your list is just a bunch of integers.
Trying the one above...

```
list = 
{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}};
color1 = {0.529`, 0.808`, 0.922`};
row = 3;
start = 2;
Part[list, row - 1 ;; row + 1, start ;; start + 2] = color1;
list
(* Output:
{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, 0.529, 0.529, 0.529, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, 0.808, 0.808, 0.808, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, 0.922, 0.922, 0.922, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}
*)
```

Not good! The Part function replaced the sublists with each element of the new sublist.
Putting the new sublist into a lower level almost works:

```
Part[list, row - 1 ;; row + 1, start ;; start + 2] = {color1};
list
(* Output:
{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {{0.529, 0.808, 0.922}}, {{0.529, 0.808, 0.922}}, {{0.529, 0.808, 0.922}}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {{0.529, 0.808, 0.922}}, {{0.529, 0.808, 0.922}}, {{0.529, 0.808, 0.922}}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {{0.529, 0.808, 0.922}}, {{0.529, 0.808, 0.922}}, {{0.529, 0.808, 0.922}}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}
*)
```

But now all the new sublists are a level too far down. Both Flatten with 2 arguments and FlattenAt don't appear to be able to rid specifically only these levels.

Is there a convenient way to get the desired output? (Shown Below)

```
{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {0.529, 0.808, 0.922}, {0.529, 0.808, 0.922}, {0.529, 0.808, 0.922}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {0.529, 0.808, 0.922}, {0.529, 0.808, 0.922}, {0.529, 0.808, 0.922}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {0.529, 0.808, 0.922}, {0.529, 0.808, 0.922}, {0.529, 0.808, 0.922}, {1, 1, 1}},
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}
```

Comment: When you `Part` assign, as a rule you should assign something that's not a list at all or an array that has the same dimensions as the `Part` your overwriting. If you do anything else, you should expect things like this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, the most concise way to do what you want that I can think of is:

```
With[{part := Part[list, row - 1 ;; row + 1, start ;; start + 2]},
  part = ConstantArray[color1, Most @ Dimensions[part]]
]
```

In short, just create a complete array that matches the dimensions of the `Part` your trying to overwrite. You're trying to overwrite a part of `list` with dimensions 3x3x3 with a list that has dimensions 3. That's why Mathematica does the assignment at a different level than you expect. The only way out of this is to match the dimensions of the old part and the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Replace at each position using `ReplacePart`:

```
pos = Tuples[{Range[row - 1, row + 1], Range[start, start + 2]}]
new = ReplacePart[list, pos -> color1]
```

(This produces a new list rather than changing the old one.)